# Connect to a database with Diesel

Tags: error-handling, database, rust

New to Rust and would like some clarification on idiomatic and readable use of Result and Error types. Here I'm simply connecting to a database using Diesel. In my opinion, the use of match and Boxing error makes be feel like there's a more concise but still readable way to do this.

```rust
fn establish_database_connection() -> Result<PgConnection, Box<std::error::Error>> {
    dotenv().ok();

    let database_url = match env::var("DATABASE_URL") {
        Ok(url) => url,
        Err(err) => return Err(Box::new(err)),
    };

    match PgConnection::establish(&database_url) {
        Ok(connection) => Ok(connection),
        Err(err) => Err(Box::new(err)),
    }
}
```